# access 2010 use only part of text field in calculated field expression

Tags: ms-access-2010

Creating a database for an online booking system. Relatively new to access but have worked out how to automatically combine two fields in a table to fill another field. Here is what I have:

There are currently three fields in question, these are:

- firstName
- Surname
- hostName

`hostName` is the calculated field and the expression is as follows:

```
[firstName] & " " & [Surname]
```

So if the value of `firstName` is "Dave" and the value of `Surname` is "Smith", the current result in `hostName` is "Dave Smith". This is fine but I want it to only combine the value of `firstName` and the first letter of `Surname` to produce something like "Dave S".

I have looked around for a way to do this and have tried some things that I thought might work based on my coding experience but it all just threw an error. Any useful links or possible solutions would be appreciated.

Thanks, Zack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Left ( Surname, 1 )
```

More information [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/String-functions-and-how-to-use-them-965efa84-7009-4603-9765-2eb4a099ec72)

.

**Also:**

> ## Calculated fields belong in queries, not tables.

More information from Allen Browne [here](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html)

Comment: Read and practice everything you can from Allen Browne.